# powershell - cannot extract a specific field from a line that was selected from a text file

Tags: powershell

Ok, so I have to make a script which needs to be passed the name of a protocol as a parameter. The script will search for said protocol in the file *c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\protocol*. If the protocol is found, then the script needs to return the port assigned to it.

I have no problem obtaining the entire line of information (which includes the assigned port) if the protocol is in that file...the problem comes when I need to extract just the port field.

Now, the reason why I specified in the title that the line comes from a text file is because I have no problem isolating a field from a specific line which, in turn, was isolated from a bunch of lines when these lines are the output of a cmdlet such as *get-process*. For example,

```
get-process | where-object {$_.ProcessName -eq "ServerManager"}
```

will yield an entire line but

```
 get-process | where-object {$_.ProcessName -eq "ServerManager"} | Select-Object CPU
```

will yield a specific field from that line.

Anyway, I apologize if the comparison is pointless or unnecessary. Here's the code for the script, which needs to be polished/finished :

```
param (
[string]$protocol
)

$lines=get-content -path c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\protocol

if ($lines -match $protocol) {

    $line=$($lines -match $protocol) 
    write-host $line #prints the entire line, port field is the second
    write-host $line.split()[0] #this prints only the first field (the protocol name)
    write-host $line.split()[1] #shouldn't this print only the second field (the assigned port)?

}

else {write-host "Protocol not found"}
```

Ok, so, again, sorry if I made this post unnecessarily long...thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the thing, the .Split() method that you are using splits on the Space character. Every space character. So if there is 8 spaces after the protocol name, and before the port, then [0] = protocol, and [8] = port. Not so useful. What would be better for you I think would be a RegEx match. Something like:

```
$lines=get-content -path c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\protocol | Where {$_ -match "^$Protocol\s+?(\d+?)"} | ForEach{$Matches[1]}
If($lines.count -gt 0){
    "$Protocol protocol found using port $Lines"
}
Else{"Protocol not found"}
```

That match looks for your protocol string, followed by any amount of whitespace (spaces, tabs, whatever), then captures the numbers that follow it. The ForEach loop outputs the numbers (the port), to be captured by $Lines. Then the rest should be easy enough to follow.

**Edit:** To expand on why it doesn't work like your Get-Process example, that's because the cmdlet Get-Process returns a collection of objects, and those objects have several properties, such as CPU, PID, Path, etc. You can select one of those properties to display as you showed. The lines in the text file are just strings. Strings are objects, sure, but they only have one functional property, and that's the text stored within them (yes, they have methods, but we're just talking properties that could store a value here). So there's no properties to select like there was when you ran Get-Process. I hope that helps clear that up.

**Edit2:** Ok, if we want to avoid RegEx (which you should totally read up on and learn if you plan to do any parsing or string manipulation), we can use split still. Grudgingly, but it can be done. I'll even make nice little objects like in Matt's example, because they're easier to work with, and better, and I was just lazy before and Matt was right.

```
$Lines = Get-Content c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\protocol |Where{$_ -notlike "#*" -and !([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_))}
$Protocols = ForEach($Line in $Lines){
    $SplitLine = $Line.split()|Where{!([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($_))}
    [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
        'ProtocolName' = $SplitLine[0]
        'Port' = $SplitLine[1]
        'Aliases' = $SplitLine[2]
        'Comment' = $SplitLine[4..($SplitLine.count)] -join " "
    }
}
```

Now $Protocols will output something like:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> $Protocols

ProtocolName                                          Port                                                  Aliases                                              Comment                                             
------------                                          ----                                                  -------                                              -------                                             
ip                                                    0                                                     IP                                                   Internet protocol                                   
icmp                                                  1                                                     ICMP                                                 Internet control message protocol                   
ggp                                                   3                                                     GGP                                                  Gateway-gateway protocol                            
tcp                                                   6                                                     TCP                                                  Transmission control protocol                       
egp                                                   8                                                     EGP                                                  Exterior gateway protocol                           
pup                                                   12                                                    PUP                                                  PARC universal packet protocol                      
udp                                                   17                                                    UDP                                                  User datagram protocol                              
hmp                                                   20                                                    HMP                                                  Host monitoring protocol                            
xns-idp                                               22                                                    XNS-IDP                                              Xerox NS IDP                                        
rdp                                                   27                                                    RDP                                                  "reliable datagram" protocol                        
ipv6                                                  41                                                    IPv6                                                 Internet protocol IPv6                              
ipv6-route                                            43                                                    IPv6-Route                                           Routing header for IPv6                             
ipv6-frag                                             44                                                    IPv6-Frag                                            Fragment header for IPv6                            
esp                                                   50                                                    ESP                                                  Encapsulating security payload                      
ah                                                    51                                                    AH                                                   Authentication header                               
ipv6-icmp                                             58                                                    IPv6-ICMP                                            ICMP for IPv6                                       
ipv6-nonxt                                            59                                                    IPv6-NoNxt                                           No next header for IPv6                             
ipv6-opts                                             60                                                    IPv6-Opts                                            Destination options for IPv6                        
rvd                                                   66                                                    RVD                                                  MIT remote virtual disk
```

And you can filter it as needed, such as Matt described, like

```
$Protocols | Where{$_.ProtocolName -ieq $Protocol}
```

Comment: Holy Moses...and to think that I was missing something silly...I'm pretty sure the teacher didn't even get into regular expressions in powershell...and this was from a recovery exam !! Anyway, thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

To compliment TheMadTechnicians answer. This should convert the text file into an object that you could reference like the ouput from other cmdlets.

```powershell
$protocols = get-content -path c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\protocol | Where-Object{$_ -and ($_ -notmatch "^#")} | ForEach-Object{
    $protocol = $_ -split '\s+'
    [pscustomobject]@{
        ProtocolName = $protocol[0]
        Port = $protocol[1]
        Alias = $protocol[2]
        Comment = $protocol[4..$($protocol.Count)] -join " "
    }
}
```

Then you could do something like this

```powershell
$protocols | Where-Object{$_.ProtocolName -eq "udp"}
```

Which would net the return

```powershell
ProtocolName Port Alias Comment               
------------ ---- ----- -------               
udp          17   UDP   User datagram protocol
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...if you excuse me, I'm gonna go lie down and cry...:S

Comment: So I guess it's not really possible to achieve without using regex?

Comment: Sure it is, split the lines, pass the array of strings created through `Where{!([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($_))}` and then [0] = Protocol, [1] = port, [2] = Alias, and [3] = first word of comment.